# Setting size restrictions for value to individual redis keys?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Is it possible to set size restriction for value in redis. For example, I want to store only values in which its size should be less than 2 MB to the redis key. value having size greater than 2 MB should be skipped.

keyName - sampleRedisKey_1

value for sampleRedisKey_1 - some value in which its size < 2 MB

keyName - sampleRedisKey_2

value for sampleRedisKey_2 - some value in which its size > 2 MB

In these two keys, sampleRedisKey_1 should be stored and sampleRedisKey_2 should not be stored.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like limits on size of individual Redis object or type, you have to handle that at application side. Otherwise use some Lua script to do that. However I prefer client side as it completely avoids sending data to Redis instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your redis version >= `4.0.0` then you may use `memory usage`, it returns the the value in bytes. In your application layer you may make comparison before setting the value, skip to another key if size exceeds.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set mykey mysmallvalue
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage mykey
(integer) 61
127.0.0.1:6379> set anotherkey 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> memory usage anotherkey
(integer) 52
127.0.0.1:6379>
```